# During recursion in a loop, index count is lost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, lodash

**Objective:**

I am developing an app using AngularJS and Lodash. I need a function that do the following transformation:

From

```
{
 a: 0,
 b: {x: {y: 1, z: 2}},
 c: 3
}
```

into

```
{
 a: 0,
 'b.x.y': 1,
 'b.x.z': 2,
 c: 3
}
```

Right now, I am using a recursive function to traverse through the object. For the time being, my code looks like that (**incomplete**):

```js
            var obj = {},
                keys, property, value;

            var recur = function (mat) {

                keys = Object.keys(mat);

                for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    property = keys[i];
                    value = mat[property];

                    if (isObj(value)) {
                        //debugger;
                        recur(value);


                    } else {
                        obj[property] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
            recur({
             a: 0,
             b: {x: {y: 1, z: 2}},
             c: 3
            });
            
            console.log(obj);
            
            function isObj(value) {
            return typeof value === "object";
        }
```

One issue that I am getting while debugging is:

**i** is not being incremented; during the highest-level recursion call, i remains 0.

Anyone knows why?
And if you know of any other way for doing this transformation, please share it.

Kind Regards.

Comment: b: {x: {y: 1}, {z: 2}} is not a valid json

Comment: @marvel308: There's no JSON in the question at all. You're right that `b: {x: {y: 1}, {z: 2}},` contains an invalid object initializer, though.

Comment: yup I think `b: {x: {y: 1}, {z: 2}}` should be `b: {x: [{y: 1}, {z: 2}]}`

Comment: My apology; correction related to JSON made.

Comment: @RamsingNadeem: There is no JSON in the question. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Yeah; my bad. It's a normal JS Object. In the app, we are getting responses in JSON from the server though, but that's not important in our context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in the following way

```js
let obj = {
 a: 0,
 b: {x: {y: 1, z: 2}},
 c: 3
}

let result = {};
function rec(obj, parent){
   
   if(typeof obj == 'object'){
      for(let property in obj){
      
          rec(obj[property], (parent == '' ? parent:parent+'.')+property);
      }
   }
   else {
      result[parent] = obj;
   }
}

rec(obj, '');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `keys` is declared in the wrong scope. It should be declared **inside** `recur`. Since it isn't, when `recur` recurses, `keys` gets overwritten.

That doesn't make `i` not increase, but it does mean your loops will terminate at surprising times because `keys` changes when you recurse.

`property` and `value` should also be declared within `recur`; in general, declare variables in the innermost scope you can. (`temp` need not be declared at all, as you never use it.)

To get your end result, obviously you have to change more than just that, but you said the code is incomplete. This is the problem with the loops not working properly.

Comment: Thanks; shall continue working on the transformation; always thought it was better to remove "var" out of loops and/or recursions for better performance (but yeah, behavior might often become abnormal).

Answer (score 2):

For converting a valid object you could use an iterative and recursive approach for getting values and their pathes.

```js
function convert(object) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            var q = p.concat(k);
            if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                iter(o[k], q);
                return;
            }
            object[q.join('.')] = o[k];
        });
    }

    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            iter(object[k], [k]);
            delete object[k];
        }
    });
}

var object = { a: 0, b: { x: { y: 1, z: 2 } }, c: 3 };

convert(object);

console.log(object);
```

Single iterator/new result

```js
function convert(object) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        p = p ? p + '.' : '';
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                iter(o[k], p + k);
                return;
            }
            result[p + k] = o[k];
        });
    }

    var result = {};
    iter(object);
    return result;
}

var object = { a: 0, b: { x: { y: 1, z: 2 } }, c: 3 };

console.log(convert(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, everyone (particularly to @T.J. Crowder for pointing out the error I've made related to scope).

My complete code (any suggestion - related to good/bad practices, etc - would be welcome):

```js
var recur = function (obj, mat, parent) {

             var keys = Object.keys(mat);

             for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    var property = keys[i];
                    var value = mat[property];

                    if (isObj(value)) {
                        recur(obj, value, parent ? parent + "." + property : property);

                    } else {
                        obj[parent ? parent + "." + property : property] = value;
                    } 
            }
            return obj;
}
            console.log(recur({}, {
             a: 0,
             b: {x: {y: 1, z: 2}},
             c: 3
            }));
            
            function isObj(value) {
            return typeof value === "object";
}
```

Comment: just a hint, if you have values, like `null`, you treat it as object (which it is), but you need to treat it as value. you need `if (value && isObj(value)) {`. i would move the declarations out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks. :D Implementing the changes asap.

Comment: But the (return typeof value === "object") inside isObj() does not already cater for null? Or can (typeof null === "object") return true?

Comment: `typeof null` is equal to `'object'`.